# changed? method not work inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following model:

```
class TicketStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :set_previous_staff
  attr_accessible :status_id, :ticket_id , :staff_id, :advisor_id, :previous_advisor_id, :previous_staff_id
  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :ticket
  belongs_to :staff, class_name: 'Staff', foreign_key: 'staff_id'
  belongs_to :previous_staff , class_name: 'Staff', foreign_key: 'previous_staff_id'
  belongs_to :advisor, class_name: 'Advisor', foreign_key: 'advisor_id'

  def set_previous_staff
    self.previous_staff_id = self.staff_id_was if self.staff_id_changed?
  end

end
```

`set_previous_staff` method is not working with the callback however i tried `changed?` in console and it should work , what is missing here ? i am using rails 3.2.14

what i expected: I have an assigned employee to a ticket , i need when that assigned employee changed, his id should be added to `previous_staff_id` , so this will let me know who is the current employee and who was before him.

Comment: Please explain how it does not work.

Comment: try with `include ActiveModel::Dirty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the instance after you update it, but you never actually save the change to the database after that.  For updating, the order goes:

1. before_validation
2. before_validation_on_update
3. after_validation
4. after_validation_on_update
5. before_save
6. before_update
7. DATABASE INSERT
8. after_update
9. after_save

Try changing `after_update` to `before_update` so that your method runs before the change is committed.

Comment: it works using before_update , so in case of after_update the if statement stay false ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking here :/

Comment: in case of after_update it was not working , but in case of before_update its working , is that because its already committed so it will be considered as not changed and then my method will not be triggered ?

Comment: Yes, Rails includes a module called `ActiveModel::Dirty` that tracks changes to instance variables from the last database commit.  If you call `changed?` right after the commit, then nothing will be different and your condition will return `false`.